# How to set JFreeChart to not order DataSet?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have small project which makes a graph plot of a data in database. One record in DB is like this:

```
ID, Name, Xcoord, Ycoord
```

For example, I've added 10 points coordinates of which is more or less like this:

```
1st(1:1) 2nd(2:2) 3rd(3:3) 4th(4:4) ... 10th(10:10);
```

After that I want to add one more point `11th(5,7:5,7)`, and 10th must connect with 11th. So line must go leftwards. Now `XYPlot` sorts my `XYDataset` and 11th point gets plotted in between of 5th and 6th Points, and I don't want that.

Can anyone help?

UPDATE : As correctly supposed by mr.Trashgod i was using org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries(), and setting autosort flag to
false lead to correct plotting.

Comment: Which `XYDataset` are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without knowing which `XYDataset` you are using, it's hard to be specific. The several `XxxSeriesCollection` subclasses typically contain series that have an optional `autoSort` parameter in the constructor. For example, an `XYSeriesCollection` contains zero or more [`XYSeries`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/XYSeries.html) with a suitable constructor:

```
XYSeries(java.lang.Comparable key, boolean autoSort)
XYSeries(java.lang.Comparable key, boolean autoSort, boolean allowDuplicateXValues)
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me alot :)
I'd be glad to give to this answer an upvote, but not enough reputation i got.