# How can I plot X,Y coordinates by added order?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I want to connect X and Y coordinates by order which I inputed to make a circle .

I found a program that draw X,Y coordinates in Java . 
Then I added my data of circle but program connected nearest X,Y coordinates not ordered X,Y .

```
public Graph(final String title) {

    super(title);
    final XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Random Data");

    series.add(2.000 , 0);
    series.add(0 , 2.000);
    series.add(-2.000 , 0);
    series.add(0 , -2.000);
    final XYSeriesCollection data = new XYSeriesCollection(series);
    final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
            "XY Series Demo",
            "X",
            "Y",
            data,
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
            true,
            true,
            false
    );
```

I expected results as square diagram .[image: result_ss]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`XYSeries`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/XYSeries.html) API specifies,

> By default, items in the series will be sorted into ascending order by x-value, and duplicate x-values are permitted.

You can defeat this with the appropriate constructor, suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14399963/230513):

```
final XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Random Data", false);
```

In the illustration below, I've added  an extra data point to close the figure:

[image]

For arbitrary shapes, also consider an `XYShapeAnnotation`, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6802375/230513).

[image]