# Connecting the points of design envelope in JFreeChart

Tags: jfreechart, envelope

Is there a way to get JFreeChart to connect all the point in this series 

`x = [0.0, 38.0, 60.0, 80.0, 100.0, 123.0, 165.0, 165.0, 0.0]
y = [0.25, 0.25 ,0.6 ,1.1 ,1.75 ,2.65 ,2.65 ,0.25, 0.25]`
 
to form an envelope?
After several attempts I could not get the beginning and the end of the plot to connect since both of them are zero on the x-axis.
Any hint will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*How can I plot X,Y coordinates by added order?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56381752/230513)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I plot X,Y coordinates by added order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380419/how-can-i-plot-x-y-coordinates-by-added-order)