# JavaFX LineChart not drawing circle?

Tags: java, javafx, charts

This chart shows the problem:

[image: the problem]

I have JavaFX program that calculates data and draws a chart, but why points are not connected properly? I have tried many things, even creating two separate series, but it doesn't work.

```
public void createScatterChart(){
    final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();

    final SmoothedChart<Number,Number> smoothedChart = new SmoothedChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);

    XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
    XYChart.Series series2 = new XYChart.Series();
    XYChart.Series series3 = new XYChart.Series();

    for(int i = 0 ; i < this.r.size() ; i ++)
    {
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(this.r.get(i) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(this.nodes.get(i))),this.r.get(i) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(this.nodes.get(i)))));
        //series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(this.r.get(i) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(this.nodes.get(i) * this.xArray[i][0])),this.r.get(i) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(this.nodes.get(i) * this.xArray[i][0]))));
    }


    smoothedChart.getData().add(series1);
    smoothedChart.getData().add(series2);
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    Scene scene  = new Scene(smoothedChart,800,600);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: Create and post a [mre].

Comment: Changing to linechart does not fix the problem

Comment: A similar problem is examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56381752/230513); maybe look at sorting policy and include it in your [mre].

Comment: Yep sorting policy worked, but I had to change chart from my SmoothChart to standard LineChart. I tried it before but I used Y_AXIS policy and it didn't work. Now I used LineChart.SortingPolicy.NONE and it fixed my problem, thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A similar problem is examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56381752/230513), in which the solution hinges on the data sort order. Looking at [`LineChart`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/chart/LineChart.html), [`SortingPolicy.NONE`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/chart/LineChart.SortingPolicy.html#NONE) specifies "The data should be left in the order defined by the list in `XYChart.dataProperty()`."

> I had to change chart from my `SmoothChart` to standard `LineChart`.

Depending on your approach to smoothing, you may encounter the kind of cubic spline artifacts examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70021577/230513), which also occurs in [jfreechart-fx](/questions/tagged/jfreechart-fx). An approach using Bézier curves is adduced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71417125/230513).

As tested using [synthetic data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2510048/230513):

[image: NONE]
[image: X_AXIS]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/72607616/230513
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2510048/230513
 */
public class ChartTest extends Application {

    private static final int N = 32;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        var xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        var yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        var series = new XYChart.Series();
        series.setName("Data");
        for (int i = 0; i <= N; i++) {
            var t = 2 * Math.PI * i / N;
            var x = Math.cos(t);
            var y = Math.sin(t);
            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(x, y));
        }
        var chart = new LineChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);
        chart.getData().add(series);
        ObservableList<LineChart.SortingPolicy> policies
            = FXCollections.observableArrayList(LineChart.SortingPolicy.values());
        var policy = new ChoiceBox<LineChart.SortingPolicy>(policies);
        policy.setTooltip(new Tooltip("Choose a data sorting policy."));
        policy.getSelectionModel().select(chart.getAxisSortingPolicy());
        chart.axisSortingPolicyProperty().bind(policy.valueProperty());
        Pane root = new StackPane(chart, policy);
        StackPane.setAlignment(policy, Pos.TOP_RIGHT);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```