# How does XYLineAndShapeRenderer connect a dataset with a graph?

Tags: java, jfreechart

Here is an example; it sets the render like this:

```
final XYPlot plot = xylineChart.getXYPlot( );
XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer( );
renderer.setSeriesPaint( 0 , Color.RED );
renderer.setSeriesPaint( 1 , Color.GREEN );
renderer.setSeriesPaint( 2 , Color.YELLOW );
renderer.setSeriesStroke( 0 , new BasicStroke( 4.0f ) );
renderer.setSeriesStroke( 1 , new BasicStroke( 3.0f ) );
renderer.setSeriesStroke( 2 , new BasicStroke( 2.0f ) );
plot.setRenderer( renderer );
```

And the data set like this:

```
final XYSeries firefox = new XYSeries( "Firefox" );
firefox.add( 1.0 , 1.0 );
firefox.add( 2.0 , 4.0 );
firefox.add( 3.0 , 3.0 );
final XYSeries chrome = new XYSeries( "Chrome" );
chrome.add( 1.0 , 4.0 );
chrome.add( 2.0 , 5.0 );
chrome.add( 3.0 , 6.0 );
final XYSeries iexplorer = new XYSeries( "InternetExplorer" );
iexplorer.add( 3.0 , 4.0 );
iexplorer.add( 4.0 , 5.0 );
iexplorer.add( 5.0 , 4.0 );
final XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection( );
dataset.addSeries( firefox );
dataset.addSeries( chrome );
dataset.addSeries( iexplorer );
```

Then the result is like this:
[image]

I can not see any code to give each data series a unique graph, but the result gives the three kinds of data the graph set before, such firefox is red, chrome is green.

**Is the graph assigned in order?**

If so, if I add another data to the dataset, which colour it will be assigned?

If not, how to connect the graph with the data? What if I want to give firefox green and chrome red?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the graph assigned in order?

An "[`XYPlot`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/XYPlot.html) makes use of an `XYItemRenderer` to draw each point on the plot." This includes all points in all series in the plot's `XYDataset`. Your example's dataset includes three series, each having three points; moreover, each point in a series is connected by a line, as your image illustrates. The order *within* an `XYSeries` is sorted by default, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14399963/230513).

> If so, if I add another data to the dataset, which colour it will be assigned? If not, how to connect the graph with the data? What if I want to give firefox green and chrome red?

Absent an explicit call to `setSeriesPaint()`, the next color is supplied by the plot's `DrawingSupplier`, discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A230513%20%5Bjfreechart%5D%20DrawingSupplier). The choice may be influenced by your use case: for example, a custom `DrawingSupplier` is warranted if the chart's plot and legend should match in a particular way, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28519356/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40545725/230513).

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!